# $a_{k+1}-a_k = a_2 - a_1$,$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}{a_k}$=?

Tags: combinatorics

I need to find an explicit formula for the sum $\sum 
\limits_{k=1}^{n}{a_k}$ where $(a_k)_{k∈ℕ}∈ℚ^ℕ$ with $a_{k+1}-a_k = a_2 - a_1$ for all k∈ℕ

I would love to start with by collecting the values of $a_k$ and $k$, but somehow I don't know what to do with $a_{k+1}-a_k = a_2 - a_1$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Clearly this is an AP. Since $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's arithmetic progression.

Common difference equals to $a_2 - a_1$, therefore
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k=\frac{2a_1 + (n-1)(a_2 - a_1)}{2}n$$